# NavBar/Header not being responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my navbar responsive so that it easy to use for my friends who check my website out on their phone. The `nav` tag consists of the list `ul` shown in the code and list items whose `id="Categories"` when I try to resize it the background color of the navbar shrink leaving some black white space and I also lose some list items.
How can I fix this?

`CSS`

```
:root {
  --primary-color: #14365d;
  --secondary-color: #d85c27;
  --text-color: aliceblue;
  --hover-color: #c5cbe3;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  padding: 1rem;
  color: var(--text-color);
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#Categories {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

`HTML`

```
<nav>
        <h2>TV Show Reviews</h2>
        <p>Check out my ratings for some of the most popular TV Shows</p>
        <ul>
          {categories.map((item) => {
            return (
              <li
                id="Categories"
                key={item}
                onClick={() => ClickHandler({ item })}
                style={{ backgroundColor: "#d85c27" }}
              >
                {item}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Here is an image of the given issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CmSe.png

Comment: Please edit to include your HTML as well.

Comment: @StephenMIrving Added my app.js file

Answer (score 0):

Some example to give you nav break point

```
@media(min-width: 768px){
  nav {
      width: 680px;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 992px){
  nav {
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

Also. When go the size smaller than 768px. W3School have some cool things to read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp)